# Macro to count first four characters in a column and give the total count to Text file

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for macro which works in counting the first four characters of a word in the column and gives the total count.

For Example:

Column A

```
tg34pc005
tg36pc008
tg34pc006
```

my expectation is macro should give out result

```
tg34 2
tg36 1
```

Comment: Why don't you show which code you have started, then definitely someone would help you

Comment: Hi, this isn't a code writing site, but a place to post code that has a specific error or unexpected output. Asking for something like this would normally be in the realm of freelancing sites where you would pay someone.  Please refer to the [FAQ](http://$SITEURL$/faq) to see what kind of questions you can ask here. Have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

No macro required

Set up your criteria as `="=tg34*"` etc.

The formula is then `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$3,cell with criteria)`

OR

Leave your criteria as `tg34`

The formula is then `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$3,"=" & cell with criteria & "*")`